# Mistakenly set Boolean attribute to Yes in lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforcedx, lightning-experience, aura, lightning-design-system

In my lightning component have an attribute defined as boolean

```
     <aura:attribute name="test" type="Boolean" default="false"/>
       ......
       .....
       //and I used it like below in an aura if condition to render the UI part

     <aura:if isTrue="{!and(v.test, v.someothertest)}"></aura:if>
```

but in controller mistakenly set this Boolean to "Yes" instead of setting it to "true"

```
     c.set("v.test", "Yes");
```

the other attribute someothertest is set to true only

surprisingly, this did not fail and never caught attention until the code is in prod, now am confused whether it should be corrected OR i can leave it as is.
Could you please help me to understand why it worked in first place..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In JavaScript, we have [Truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [Falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values. As long as the value is truthy, then `aura:if` will render its true path, and while the attribute is falsy, it will render its `else` attribute.

Basically, anything that's not falsy is truthy, and the only falsy values you're likely to encounter are: `false`, `0`, `-0`, `0n`, `''` (any empty string), `null`, `undefined`, `NaN` (not a number, such as an invalid date or string that can't be parsed as a number). `document.all` is also falsy, but you're not likely to use that in real code.

You can leave the code there from a technical perspective. JavaScript doesn't care. `"Yes"` is a truthy value. However, `"No"` is also a truthy value. If you leave it there, a future developer might see that the attribute appears to be "Yes"/"No" and decide to add code to undo the setting as `c.set("v.test", "No")`, then not be able to figure out why it's not working correctly. So, from a code quality standpoint, I recommend you fix it to avoid potential future problems.

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation, it helps..:)